# Name of contact pins of Canon mount and where to buy it?

Tags: lens, canon, diy, lens-mount

I want to convert my Canon lens into a macro lens. I really need the contact pins to customize the ring so the aperture will work. But I can't find it anywhere.

Does somebody know the name of this contact pins and where I can buy one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know whether you want to just connect wires to the pins, or have them do something else, but a start would be to do a search for "AF confirm Canon". All of these chips will have the correct format, but I'm not sure how easy it is to remove the AF confirm chip.

Comment: Awesome, that's it. Thank you for that! Can't be that hard. I just want to connect the pins with wires.

Comment: Further research on the AF confirm led to an end. It is not what I was searching for, close though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oke after a lot of searching I found the items

```
1 x Lens Contact Assembly for Canon (part in the camera itself)
1 x Canon Lens Mount Repair Part (plastic mount of the lens)
1 x Contact Assembly with Flex for Canon Lens (part in the lens)
2 x rear lens cover
2 x camera body cover
```

The parts where around €85 in total. That is not what I was hoping for a few pieces of plastic.

The lens contact assembly from the camera and contact assembly from the lens are the most expensive. I will search for an alternative way to mod my lens. I am thinking about using my old floppy IDE cable and the rear lens covers to mod them that the pins of the IDE cable touch the lens contacts when put on the lens and the other side of the IDE cable touch the contacts in the camera when putting on that side of the adapter and cover. To bad the original parts are so expensive.

Comment: You could probably do this a lot cheaper by buying a couple of damaged lenses and camera bodies. I can't imagine a broken EOS3000 film body will go for much on eBay...

Comment: Found the cheapest one for €27, only body, So I only can take out the lens contact assembly i need.It's cheaper to buy that piece only. But yes, I will search for broken lenses and body's. Maybe I can find one for like €30 complete with lens broken and all. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to purchase a EF extension tube that supports AF. This contains the contacts that contact the camera body and the pins that contact the lens. Just a case of disassembling and then soldering the floppy wire between the two parts.

I have been wanting to do the same mod myself for some time, but haven't got round to it yet. Have a look at the "Meike Auto Focus AF Macro Extension Tube for kenko Canon" for sale on eBay, which seems to be the cheapest AF extension tubes you can get. You could probably resell the two unused tubes to recoup some of your costs as well (if you didn't want them).